# Getting a max Date Value of a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, group-by

I would like to combine multiple columns in a dataframe with specific aggregate functions depending on the column type. But I am having issues with the date column.

I am initialising a dataframe with 2 rows:

```
import pandas as pd 

data1 = [['Treuman', 0, 'System_0', '2023-07-21'], ['Treuman', 1, 'System_1', "2023-07-21"]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Name', 'Grades', 'Systems', 'Request Date']) 

df.head()
```

Looking like this:

```
Name    Grades  Systems Request Date
0   Treuman 0   System_0    2023-07-21
1   Treuman 1   System_1    2023-07-21
```

After this I aggregate the rows based on the Name column:

```
df = df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False).agg({'Grades': sum,
                                                'Systems': lambda x: ','.join(x),
                                                'Request Date': lambda g: g.loc[pd.to_datetime(df["Request Date"]).idxmax(skipna=True)]
                                                })
df.head()
```

This results in what I want:

```
Name    Grades  Systems Request Date
0   Treuman 1   System_0,System_1   2023-07-21
```

Now if I try to add a unique column this code does not work.

```
data2 = [['Treuman', 0, 'System_0', '2023-07-21'], ['Treuman', 1, 'System_1', "2023-07-21"], ['Oldman', 1, 'System_1', "2023-06-21"]]
```

I am getting this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3802, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801 try:
-> 3802     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803 except KeyError as err:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2263, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py:297, in SeriesGroupBy.aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    296 try:
--> 297     return self._python_agg_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
    298 except KeyError:
    299     # TODO: KeyError is raised in _python_agg_general,
...
   3807     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3808     #  the TypeError.
   3809     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 0
```

It seems the issue is the lambda funcytion for the date column, as it is not finding a max value, due to being a unique row. How can I get this working also with unique rows?

```
Name    Grades  Systems Request Date
0   Treuman 1   System_0,System_1   2023-07-21
1   Oldman 1   System_1  2023-06-21
```

Can anybody give me a lead on why the date columns is an issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to use iloc?

```
data2 = [['Treuman', 0, 'System_0', '2023-07-21'], ['Treuman', 1, 'System_1', "2023-07-21"], ['Oldman', 1, 'System_1', "2023-06-21"]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Name', 'Grades', 'Systems', 'Request Date']) 
df = df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False).agg({'Grades': sum,
                                                'Systems': lambda x: ','.join(x),
                                                'Request Date': lambda g: g.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df["Request Date"]).idxmax(skipna=True)]
                                                })
```